# 3 or more machines communicate

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

through the tutorials(http://wiki.ros.org/cn/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) i konw how to communicate between two machine,but i want to konw if i have three or more computers and I want they  can communicate with each other,what I should do ,just use "export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://hal:11311" in every computers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220606/3-or-more-machines-communicate/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If that is the IP address where roscore was run then yes. On each machine you also need to export that machines own IP address (no port number needed) - we have found we had to  "export ROS_HOSTNAME=" whatever the address is and
"export ROS_IP=" too, to avoid AF_INET errors

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on 2015-11-08**:
thank you ,i will try it